# GitHub: can't push new project to repo, green button "Compare & pull request" appears

Tags: git, github

When I push from my new Angular project to its new GitHub repo no code files appear in GitHub. Instead I get a yellow message with a green button that says `Compare & pull request`:

[image]

When I click the green button I see a diff showing changes to files. I don't see a button saying "Approve". I don't see any buttons to click.

My `.git > config` file looks good:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
# [remote "MyNewAngularProject"]
#   url = https://github.com/tdkehoe/MyNewAngularProject
#   fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/MyNewAngularProject/*
# [branch "master"]
#   remote = MyNewAngularProject
#   merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/tdkehoe/MyNewAngularProject
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "cleanup"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/cleanup
[branch "rama"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/rama
```

At the CLI everything looks good:

```
$ git remote
origin
```

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/tdkehoe/MyNewAngularProject (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/tdkehoe/MyNewAngularProject (push)
```

In GitHub I tried `Add file > Upload files`, selected a file, and a second later the file was in my repo. Everything is hooked up.

What I expect to happen when I push is, I first run `git status`. I see my modified files in red.

If I want them all I run `git add *.*`. Or I add the files I want and put the unwanted files into my `.gitignore` file.

Then I run  `git status` again and I see the modified files in green.

Then I run `git commit -m 'Fixed a bug that was bugging me'"`

Then I run `git push origin master`.

Then I see some messages and the files magically appear in my GitHub repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pushed your master branch to Github, but it looks to me like it is treated like any other unknown branch. Your github repo probably has a different "main" branch. Github has changed the default branch to `main` (for better or worse). You will have to look in your repo what is configured. It will be the branch picked for you on the main github project page.

The green button not only shows you the diff. You can also create a pull request to the configured "main" branch (or any other you pick). Once you have a pull request you can merge it.

You can obliviously change the `main` branch back to `master` or use `main` in your local project. However you like.

Comment: GitHub changed "master" to "main". You'd think they could make this throw an error message. I like that you told me to "obliviously" change master to main or vice versa. Oblivious is this makes me feel! :-)

Comment: @ThomasDavidKehoe ups sometimes my hands have a mind of their own, I swear. sorry ;-)